# How to export a non PMML Algorithm for predicting the values in another JVM Process

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

we are trying to use Spark MLLib algorithm "Linear Support Vector Machine Algorithm" to predict values, where a certain featured people will be tend to fall sick. So we have the model built on top of spark. But i want to export this model and use it for predicting the values for actual data using another JVM process( like i have data streaming from kafka and using java i want to give result for given record whether that person is prone to fall sick). Is there a way to export this model as we do in PMML support algorithms and use that model to predict the values.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Jagadeesh Pavan.